# Mod_rewrite directory requests

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do this:
example.com/directory/song.mp3 -> Unchanged
example.com/directory/ -> example.com/?dir=directory%2F
example.com/ -> Unchanged
example.com/index.php -> Unchanged

Basically, if a user requests any directory other than root, I need it rewritten, not redirected, to index.php?dir=< path with slashes changed to %2F>
I want the user to still see example.com/path/to/stuff in their browser, but the request to be rewritten serverside.

example.com/songs/stuff -> example.com/?dir=songs%2Fstuff%2F

I hope I am clear about what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+/.*) /index.php?dir=$1
```

Comment: I just tested this and it gave me an internal server error. I tried loading http://127.0.0.1/opentape/ The rewrite rule shouldn't have rewritten that should it?

Comment: Error on my part. I added RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d because it was rewriting stylesheet url's. Only problem is that it rewrites to index.php as a relative path, resulting in 404 errors. test.com/dir/ gets rewritten to test.com/dir/index.php?dir=/dir instead of test.com/index.php?dir=/dir. Also, is there a way to make the redirect server side? I would like the test.com/dir/ to remain in the browser window.

Comment: Meh, this question is messed up. It's working kinda. I'll start a new question for the problems I am now having. Thanks.